# How do I create a static library with C or C++ linkage from a Perl module?

Tags: perl, visual-c++, static-libraries

I have a very big Perl module, and I am expecting to call it in my Visual C++ project. I know there are tools like *perl2exe* and *pp* that can convert Perl modules to standalone executables (`abc.exe`).

I don't like the standalone executable because it makes the interface very complex. I have to call the Perl module by creating a process and communicating with it using standard input/output.

It will be much easier if the Perl module is a C/C++ static library. Just link it and call a function!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (yet|easily) compile modules. Instead, [embed the Perl interpreter as a library](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, I have to deliver my perl module in source code format together with my c++ executable. Am I right?

Comment: To be fair, `perl2exe` also delivers the Perl source.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed statically link your module into your C project. The thing to realise is that you need to link in `perl` too. `perl` is a library heavily used by Perl code (and it would be so even if Perl code could be compiled to machine language).

[perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) documents how to do this.

Comment: My understanding about perlembed is that it is able to create a Perl interpreter inside a C/C++ program. And through that interpreter you can call your Perl module. The Perl module is still in a standalone *.pm file. I am new to Perl, so I am not very sure.

Comment: @user1444658, It doesn't need to be an external file. You can pass the .pm's Perl contents to the interpreter, and you can link any XS component to your executable.